# Huge Performance difference when assign an integer to a varchar column on where clause

Tags: mysql

I hava a table say table A and it has a varchar(120) column say column_x. This table have approximately 4 million records. Table A created a index on column column_x. When i do a `select` query, i accident assign a `integer` to column_x. The query looks like this:

```
select * from A where column_x = 12345
```

This query finished after about 20s later. And when i rewrite the query like this:

```
select * from A where column_x = '12345'
```

The query finished immediately. Then i uses the `explain` statements, and the result is this:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: mt_tm_day
         type: ALL
possible_keys: idx_mt_tm_day_ps_id
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4129271
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: A
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_on_column_x
          key: index_on_column_x
      key_len: 363
          ref: const
         rows: 116
        Extra: Using index condition
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So my question is what happened when assign an integer to a varchar column on where clause.

Comment: key NULL table scan no index use 4.1M rows vs. 116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, the difference is the use of the index.  When an index is used, the lookup is very, very fast.  Without an index, the query requires a full table scan.

The question is why this query does not use an index:

```
select * from A where column_x = 12345
```

The type conversion rules are explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/type-conversion.html).  But, the key point is this:

> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

What this says is that the *column* is converted to a number, rather than the constant being converted to a string.  So, your query is equivalent to:

```
where cast(column_x as float) = cast(12345 as float)
```

When a function is used on a column, MySQL can no longer take advantage of an index.  Without the index, the query has to do a full table scan.

Moral of the story:  When comparing values, try to be sure that the types are the same.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html), when you compare a `VARCHAR` and an `INT`, the comparison is done by converting both to floating point numbers. This combination isn't specifically mentioned in any of the bullets, so the last one applies:

> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

As a result, the comparison can't use the index of the column, because the index just contains the original string, not its value as a number. So it has to go through every row of the table, convert the string to a number, and compare that with `12345`.